# Calling "dismiss" on SnackbarHostState doesn't do anything

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to use flows in Kotlin to handle UI events. I was able to have a Snackbar message system working correctly, except that even If I call `dismiss` on the SnackbarHostState, the messages are still queued until the user manually dismisses it or the timer runs out. Here is how I handle all of this:

This is the `callbackFlow` setup:

```kotlin
private fun snackbarFlow() = callbackFlow {
        val callback = object : SnackbarListener {
            override fun showSnackbar(message: String) {
                trySend(Pair(message, false))
            }

            override fun errorSnackbar(message: String) {
                trySend(Pair(message, true))
            }
        }

        snackbarListener = callback

        awaitClose { snackbarListener = null }
    }
```

where `snackbarListener` implements the `SnackbarListener` defined as

```kotlin
private interface SnackbarListener {
        fun showSnackbar(message: String)
        fun errorSnackbar(message: String)
    }
```

I then have an initialization function which launches the collection of data from the flow:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun InitSnackbarFlow() {
            val snackbarHostState = currentSnackbarHostState

            LaunchedEffect("SnackbarFlow") {
                snackbarFlow().collect { (message, isError) ->
                    Logger.d(LOG_TAG, "SNACKBAR FLOW: $message")
                    _snackbarState.update { SnackBarState(message, isError) }
                    snackbarHostState.currentSnackbarData?.dismiss()
                    snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(message, duration = SnackbarDuration.Short, withDismissAction = true)
                }
            }
        }
```

where `_snackbarState = MutableStateFlow(SnackBarState(message = ""))` with

```kotlin
data class SnackBarState(
        val message: String = "",
        val isError: Boolean = false
    )
```

In the main composable, I have

```kotlin
val snackbarState: SnackbarState by snackbarState.collectAsState()
val snackbarHostState = currentSnackbarHostState

Scaffold(snackbarHost = {
        SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) { data ->
            if (snackbarState.isError) {
                Snackbar(
                    data, containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error
                )
            } else Snackbar(data)
        }
    }
```

This is called inside a `CompositionLocalProvider(LocalSnackbarHostState provides snackbarHostState)`, with `val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }`, `val LocalSnackbarHostState = compositionLocalOf { SnackbarHostState() }` and

```kotlin
currentSnackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState
    @Composable
    @ReadOnlyComposable
    get() = LocalSnackbarHostState.current
```

Sorry for the amount of code, but this is the setup I'm using. As stated above, this works perfectly fine: calling `snackbarListener.showSnackbar` does work, except the line `snackbarHostState.currentSnackbarData?.dismiss()` does nothing. Logging `snackbarHostState.currentSnackbarData` it shows that it is `null`, but `currentSnackbarHostState` should provide the correct state at all time.

I've also tried calling `dismiss` directly in the `Scaffold` object, but this causes the snackbar not to show at all (probably it gets dismissed as soon as it is created? not sure).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. `snackbarHostState.showSnackbar` called inside the collected flow is blocking the closure until the snackbar disappears. Thus, the next value received by the flow is collected when the snackbar is already gone, thus `snackbarHostState.currentSnackbarData` is `null` and `dismiss()` doesn't run. The solution was to put `dismiss` and `showSnackbar` inside a closure passed to `launch`, avoiding the blocking of the `collect` closure.